# Wifi isn't working

Tags: internet, ethernet

I'm using a live ubuntu session, just to feel it out and make sure there were no problems before I completely installed and removed the mac osx os. But for some reason I cannot access the internet wirelessly, no networks come up, it's as if I don't even have a wifi card. Can someone help me out please? It's weird because when I use the mac os, I can use wifi no problem. (sorry, here's the output)

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4321 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4328] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. AirPort Extreme [106b:0088]
    Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Comment: If that's the issue, how would I go about correcting it?

Comment: The hardware was successfully recognized. Seems like something is "blocking" the connection. Please edit the question with the output of the commands `dmesg | grep Wireless` and `iwconfig`. I see you haven't told us your Ubuntu version, so please **add more details**.

Comment: Also take note of the driver in use: `b43-pci-bridge`.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the live session wasn't allowing me to connect to wifi. After I installed Ubuntu and removed the mac os, the wifi is working like a charm. Thanks everyone for trying to help :D